# Web based dynamic graph - to input user preferences

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm struggling with ways how to input user preferences for given set.

I have discrete set of (up to 20) elements, ie I have list of 5 items: `cat`, `dog`, `fish`, `chameleon`, `snake`
and what I want is to draw simple graph with `n` sliders each from `0..100%`.

For example if user preferences (as home pet) `cat: 95%`, `dog: 80%`, `fish: 65%`, `chameleon: 20%` and `snake: 0%`, I want him to be able to draw this curve.

I also want sliders and titles (ie, cat, dog...) for X-coordinate to by automatically generated based on elements of the list (Y-coordinate should be %).

---

How difficult is that?

*(use jQuery or silverlight***?**)_

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want a histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create sliders. You can use [jQueryUI Sliders](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/). You can get all the values from each slider.

Once you have the values, you can use a plotting plugin like jqplot (http://www.jqplot.com/).